# can't import gltf with khr_materials_variants

Tags: gltf

[image]

trying to import glb file with khr_materials_variants i installed these extensions

[image]

but still can't import it, is there any extension i need to install too?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got an old version there (glTF Import/Export v3.2.40 is displayed).

I just tested (using [the shoe](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Assets/blob/main/Models/MaterialsVariantsShoe/README.md)) with Blender 3.6.1 (which ships with glTF I/O v3.6.27) and material variants are supported directly in that version (without the need for an additional add-on).  The add-on preferences page has a checkbox for "Material Variants" that enables some extra UI to support this.

[image: screenshot]